# Reprojected output data has different shape than input

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I am using the [python gdal library](https://gdal.org/python/) and the warp method (`osgeo.gdal.Warp`) and I have it set up like the below.

```
warped = gdal.Warp(
    destNameOrDestDS=destNameOrDestDS,
    srcDSOrSrcDSTab=srcDSOrSrcDSTab,
    srcSRS=srcSRS,
    dstSRS=dstSRS,
    dstNodata=float(srcNodata),
    format=fmt,
)
```

What I have noticed is that my output (x,y) shapes are different than my input.  Then when reverse the operation they change again, both times increasing.  Is this the expected behavior?  Am I missing some option that would keep these values stable?  I thought maybe I need to input a cell size or something, but I do not see that in the options.  I am a programmer, not GIS expert so maybe this is a lack of understanding on my part.

EDIT:

As a follow up to the below comment and answer, why can I transform a single point as in the [python gdal/ogr cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html)?

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(2927)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT (1120351.57 741921.42)")
point.Transform(transform)

print point.ExportToWkt()
```

What I had intended to do once I saw this behavior was transform the points individually instead of using the warp method.  What would have occurred in this instance?  I feel like warp is the better way to go I just want to be able to explain it.

Data Source:

```
https://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/weather/netcdf/2020/20200330/QPE.2020033012.nc.gz
srcSRS = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'
dstSRS = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 datum=NAD83 +towgs84=1,1,-1,0,0,0,0 +units=m"
dstNodata=-999.0
```

The above are the parameters that I use, if applicable.

Comment: You'd need to provide the input and output spatial reference names for even a GIS expert to predict what shape changes to expect, but changes to shape would be expected in most reprojection combinations.

Comment: @Vince, thanks for the answer, I added a follow up in my question if you can take a look.

Comment: _"Then when reverse the operation they change again, both times increasing. Is this the expected behavior?"_ - No, it isn't. The reverse must return the original shape, with a minimal round trip error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, to look at the actual data input and output would be better but what you are describing is what reprojection does. If you are a programmer I will speak a bit more in terms of math. All reprojections are is matrix transformation. Different projections use different math to flatten the 3D earth into a 2D object. This means that you must chose to shrink and stretch certain parts of the globe (imagine flattening an orange peel that was peeled in one piece) and this is where difference in projections come in.

That being said, when you reproject an object (say a perfect circle in your first projection), your output will be a warped circle in the new projection. When you go back and it is not perfect, this is a byproduct of multi-projection shifting. Reprojecting between projections that are similar should not cause many issues but if you were to write a for loop for example that reprojected an object over and over again back and forth, you will see chaos come out due to rounding and precision issue in the matrix transformations.

EDIT: For new follow-up asked.

I understand that this can start to get confusing when we start to compare points, lines, and polygons in terms of reprojecting - even I am still confused by it and I work in the GIS field. For me though, as a mathematician, I often think about points as infinitesimally small and having no area and this is where projecting starts to get weird. Every lat/lon in one projection maps to another lat/lon in the other projection (except for projections where that point may not exist - take Antartica for example). Where things can get a little weird is precision. By definition, precision means infinity cannot be reached and as a byproduct of this, finite precision means points here actually do have area.

If we use the Mercator projection as an example, we know Greenland appears way bigger(about 14 times bigger than it is) in this projection (I know this is a polygon but stay with me) and we can reasonably assume that a lat/lon with high precision from a projection that has Greenland as the correct size can (in theory) equate to a larger set of points in Mercator because this area is stretched and therefore our point of high precision before can actually be in a bubble 14 sizes larger and still technically be accurate. This is why reprojecting back and forth can cause geometry movement because computers (by nature of being finite) need to truncate or extend precision based upon the projection and the area they lie in (think stretch and shrink).

To answer what I think you are asking though, the difference between deconstructing a polygon into points, reprojecting those points, and then putting them back together is a waste. These geospatial packages optimize this stuff and going that route on your own won't decrease run time or reprojection precision (I think). Again, I could be not explaining this well or wrong on some aspects but this is how I think about it. Lastly, I suggest watching [this Vox video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIID5FDi2JQ) on map projections as they do a good job at visualization. Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added a follow up in my question if you can take a look.

Comment: Okay I have updated on what I think you are asking. Sorry if I failed to do so haha

Comment: Not going to say I understand everything you said, but it is an answer.  I will watch the video for more input.